# iphone 4 unlock

Tags: unlock

A friend of mine got a locked iPhone 4 from the US. Now she's trying to unlock it, but there's no unlock code available for iOS 4.2.1 with baseband 3.10.01. After a lot of searching I found two twitter accounts supposedly to be the masters of unlocking - Hashim Sherif and MuscleNerd.

Can someone tell me if these two are credible guys? And are there only 2 people in the whole world who can unlock the iPhone?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of prominent people in the Jailbreak community, MuscleNerd and Hashim Sherif are both key member of the [iPhone "Dev-Team"](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/).  Follow that link for updated news regarding iOS 4.3 and the 3.10.01 baseband unlock.  The following twitter users are also recommended:

- @chpwn
- @MuscleNerd
- @posixNinja
- @comex
- @pod2g

And a good explanation of what's going on:

- http://www.redmondpie.com/iphone-4-ios-4.3-unlock-on-3.10.01-and-2.10.04-baseband/
- http://pastie.org/1656829
- http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is find the relevant iClarified tutorial here: http://iclarified.com/tutorials/iphone/

You can also use their jailbreak / unlock wizards to find out exactly what the status is of your friend's model / iOS version / baseband.

You should strongly discourage your friend accepting any new versions of the iOS from Apple via iTunes. She should hold tight and wait for announcements from the jailbreak/unlock community about when and how to update her firmware. There's not really any need to contact anyone directly.